# Update values inside array of objects using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to add meeting events using Google Calendar API. In that I want to update my email in below ela object using hooks I mean to say that I want to update my email abc1@gmail.com  `'attendees': [ {'email': 'abc1@gmail.com'},]` every time I take input using given form.

```
    function App() {
      var ela={
        'attendees': [ 
          {'email': 'abc1@gmail.com'},
          {'email': 'abc2@gmail.com'}
        ]
      }
      const [formDB,setFormDB]=useState(ela);
         
      const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
          console.log('loaded client')
    
          gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'))
    
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
          .then(() => {
            
           // var event=formDB;
            console.log(formDB);
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
              'calendarId': 'primary',
              'resource': formDB,
            })
    
              request.execute(formDB => {
              console.log(formDB)
              window.open(formDB.htmlLink)
            })}
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
         // I need to fix this onChange eventin following input. Everytime I am trying to change using below logic it's saying 
         <input
            type="email"
            name="formDB.attendees[0].email"
            value={formDB.attendees[0].email}
            onChange={e=>setFormDB({ ...formDB.attendees[0], email: e.target.value})}  **fix this**
          />
         <input type="submit" name="Confirm" />
        </form>
         </div>
      );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You initialize your state with an object that has an array 'attendees'. But your onChange overwrites it with you first attendee entry. after that there is no array and all indexer accesses will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue - State Shape Mutation

```
setFormDB({ ...formDB.attendees[0], email: e.target.value})
```

You are mutating the state shape from

```
{ attendees: [] }
```

to

```
{ email: string }
```

There is no longer a `formDB.attendees` array, so attempting to access `formDB.attendees[0]` throws an error since `formDB.attendees` is undefined.

## Solution - Maintain the State Invariant

It seems you are attempting to update the first email in the array. When updating values in arrays in react state you need to shallow copy the entire array, and then update the index/element. In fact, when updating *any* nested state you need to shallow copy any nested objects your are updating.

```
<input
  type="email"
  name="formDB.attendees[0].email"
  value={formDB.attendees[0].email}
  onChange={e => setFormDB({
    ...formDB,
    attendees: formDB.attendees.map((el, i) => i === 0 ? { email: e.target.value } : el)
  })}
/>
```

Alternatively since you are always updating the first email you can create a new array, replacing the first element and slice in the rest of attendees array.

```
<input
  type="email"
  name="formDB.attendees[0].email"
  value={formDB.attendees[0].email}
  onChange={e => setFormDB({
    ...formDB,
    attendees: [{ email: e.target.value }, ...formDB.attendees.slice(1)],
  })}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. Yeah there I was missing.